# Почему как стартовую команду применяют фразу «три-четыре»?

Tags: идиомы

Почему когда русскоязычный человек начинает физическую нагрузку, он иногда говорит фразу «Три, четыре»? Почему пропускают «раз два»?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84103/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-b-------).

Comment: ["ТРИ, ЧЕТЫРЕ!" как стартовая команда](https://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/840870.html) обсуждение и версии

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Подытоживая [обсуждение](https://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/840870.html) (спасибо @Баян_Купи-ка за ссылку):

- "Три-четыре" пошло из музыки/танцев и используется для синхронизации исполнителей в начале исполнения: на "раз" уже нужно начать играть/танцевать. Если просто сказать "раз", никто не успеет начать. Поэтому дается подготовительное ["И!..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKNfwSPg5nc) или "три-четыре". Последнее лучше, чем "и", так как вдобавок задает темп. Большинство музыкальных произведений имеет четырехдольный размер, поэтому "три-четыре".

Answer (score 3):

In music, it is customary for the conductor to count one measure before the band starts. Time signature of 4/4 being standard, раз, два. три, четыре is the signal to start. Три, четыре is simply an abbreviation.